# Upgrade Awstats 6.9 to 7.0 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04, upgrade

I want to take advantage of the new features in the latest version of Awstats on 10.04 but dont want to upgrade the OS as other software I am using requires that specific OS version.

Is there any way to upgrade? Already tried using aptitude and 6.9 is the latest version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest from:

```
http://awstats.sourceforge.net/#DOWNLOAD
```

Extract the archive:

Copy:

```
awstats-7.0\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl
```

To:

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin
```

Copy:

```
awstats-7.0\wwwroot\cgi-bin\lang
awstats-7.0\wwwroot\cgi-bin\lib
awstats-7.0\wwwroot\cgi-bin\plugins
awstats-7.0\awstats-7.0\wwwroot\icon
```

To:

```
/usr/share/awstats
```

Open Webmin, Webmin Configuration, Webmin Modules, then browse for the file

```
awstats-7.0\awstats-7.0\tools\webmin\awstats-1.9.wbm
```

and install.

Update should now be complete.

Have answered my own question here: https://www.virtualmin.com/node/21442